# Can't get the FOCUS function to work except the last one

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function() {
var default_val = "Name";
jQuery("input[name='first_name']").val(default_val)
.focus(function() {
if (jQuery(Name).val() == default_val) {
jQuery(this).val("")
}
});
var default_val = "Email Address";
jQuery("input[name='email']").val(default_val)
.focus(function() {
if (jQuery(this).val() == default_val) {
jQuery(this).val("")
}
});
var default_val = "Practice Name";
jQuery("input[name='practice_name']").val(default_val)
.focus(function() {
if (jQuery(this).val() == default_val) {
jQuery(this).val("")
}
});
var default_val = "Practice Website URL";
jQuery("input[name='practice_url']").val(default_val)
.focus(function() {
if (jQuery(this).val() == default_val) {
jQuery(this).val("")
}
});
var default_val = "Telephone";
jQuery("input[name='phone_number']").val(default_val)
.focus(function() {
if (jQuery(this).val() == default_val) {
jQuery(this).val("")
}
});
});

</script>
```

Comment: Post your full code please, preferable a demo.

Comment: You only have one `default_val` variable. Every time you set it equal to something, you're overriding the previous value.

Comment: So would I just add a number to it like "default_val_1"?

Comment: Check out the placeholder attribute

Comment: Yeah I'm not a JS coder, it's really pathetic I know but I copied and pasted this to an Unbounce page I'm trying to setup... is there a simple fix relative to the code I have?

Answer (score 0):

You can use different variable for setting default value for each input to avoid overriding the value. For example:

**HTML:**

```
<input name="practice_url" value="" />
<input name="phone_number" value="" />
```

**JS:**

```
jQuery(function() { 
var default_val_practice_url = "Practice Website URL";
jQuery("input[name='practice_url']").val(default_val_practice_url)
.focus(function() {
if (jQuery(this).val() == default_val_practice_url) {
jQuery(this).val("")
}
});
var default_val = "Telephone";
jQuery("input[name='phone_number']").val(default_val)
.focus(function() {
if (jQuery(this).val() == default_val) {
jQuery(this).val("")
}
});
});
```

**JS fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/22mo0mL3/
BTW, you can use jquery-placeholder library. It's also cool!
(https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder)

Comment: Thank you for the help, I am starting to understand.

Comment: If you think the answer which you are acceppted then please check it to help the others are easy to see and find out.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `default_val` for everything. Instead of using that, use variable names that make sense like `deafult_name`, `default_email`, `default_url` etc. Also, it is probably best practice to put these kind of static variables at the top of the code

Answer (score 0):

Note: You should look into using the [`placeholder` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) instead.

---

You are using the `default_val` variable inside the callback functions that are passed to the `.focus()` method. The value of that variable when the callbacks are called is not the value when the `.focus()` method is called.

You could move your repetitive code into a function:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    function setDefaultValue($input, defaultValue) {
        $input.val(defaultValue).focus(function() {
            var $input = $(this);
            if ($input.val() == defaultValue) {
                $input.val("");
            }
        });  
    }

    setDefaultValue($("input[name='first_name']"), "Name");
    setDefaultValue($("input[name='email']"), "Email Address");
    setDefaultValue($("input[name='practice_name']"), "Practice Name");
    setDefaultValue($("input[name='practice_url']"), "Practice Website URL");
    setDefaultValue($("input[name='phone_number']"), "Telephone");
});
```

Note:

1. The `jQuery` object is passed as a parameter to callback function that is passed to the `jQuery()` function. The code above uses this fact so the `jQuery` object can safely be referenced using `$`.
2. Inside the callback function passed to the focus method, `this` refers to the element on which `.focus()` is called.

Comment: I see what you did there.  Thank you for the help!